# Two ways of writing coordinate basis vectors confusion

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

In Schutz's *A First Course in General Relativity* (p122) he derives the polar coordinate basis vector$$\vec{e_{r}}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\vec{e_{x}}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\vec{e_{y}.}$$
 But in other relativity texts I've seen coordinate basis vectors given simply as the partial derivative operator:$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}.$$
 These two equations look different to me. How do they relate to each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing $\vec{e}_r = \partial_r$, $\vec{e}_x = \partial_x$ transforms the "$\vec{e}$-notation" into the partial-derivative-notation, so the "relation" is just that $\vec{e}_{x^\mu} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}$.

Comment: Sorry to be so slow, but do you mean my first equation can be written as $$\vec{e_{r}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}.$$

Comment: @Peter4075: Yes - that's just the chain rule, if you look closely.

Comment: Expressing basis vectors as partial derivative operators still looks weird to me, but you've answered my question. Thanks.

Comment: @Peter4075: You have to realize those are not *arbitrary* vectors we express as derivatives, but [*tangent vectors*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space), and tangent vectors are rather naturally associated to derivatives

Comment: @Peter4075 This is something that a lot of people get confused by. Read section 4.1 "Vectors and Co-vector Fields", starting on page 28, from the following lecture notes. http://people.physics.tamu.edu/pope/grav-phys.pdf

Comment: @ArturodonJuan the link isn’t working. Can you provide the correct link again please

Comment: The link is for Christopher Pope’s lecture notes for his gravitational physics course. Here’s an updated link: http://people.tamu.edu/~c-pope/GravPhys2019/grav-phys.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The first expression is a single equation expressing equality between two vectors. The second expression is in [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) or rather [index notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_notation). It is a set of 4 equations (for mu=0..3) expressing equality between components of vectors. Both expressions are equivalent ways of working with vectors. Einstein notation can be much faster to manipulate.